# How to force OpenCV's imshow to update the image window?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am semantically segmenting images within a video sequence and displaying the result within a display window in real-time. However, my code is "dropping frames" by not updating the display window with each call to `imshow`.

Below is a code extract that demonstrates my problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < images->size(); i++)
{
    Mat frame = images->getImage(i);

    // semantic segmentation code (omitted)
    Mat frame_overlay = ...

    // problem: the window "seg result" does not always update
    imshow("seg result", frame_overlay);
    int key = waitKey(1);
    if (key == 27)
        break;
}
```

As a work around I can increase the wait time from 1 ms to 10 ms in the call to `waitKey`, but surely there has to be a better way of doing this.

How can I force the `"seg result"` window to update with the new `frame_overlay` image?

Comment: Run in release maybe?

Comment: I am running in release.

Comment: If your semantic segmentation code is fast (<10ms or so) then what might be happening is that you draw faster than your monitor refresh speed and the frames get "lost"

Comment: No, this cannot be the case here, as simply playing back the images without any intermediary processing (i.e. a faster frame rate) does not result in dropped frames.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038606/opencv-imshow-freezes-when-updating