# cv2.imshow not working when using with plt.show

Tags: opencv, matplotlib

I am working on opencv4 and python 3 with matplotlib version 3.2.0 .

```
cv2.imshow("Original",image)
#after few lines
plt.plot(hist)
plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.show()
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The image is not displayed but only the plt.show is displayed. 
The image is displayed after closing the graph. I want them to be showed together, is it possible?
This is the first time I am using matplotlib and only installed python3-tk. Is there anything else I should do? Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plt.show() waits when you close plot window.
imshow waits for waitKey call to show window.
Put waitKey(205) just after imshow, it should work.

Comment: For some strange reason, the image doesn't get displayed and  the window shows 'Image is not responsive' when I put waitKey(5) after imshow

Comment: Check this topic please, seems it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038606/opencv-imshow-freezes-when-updating

Comment: Though waitKey(25) didnot work, waitKey(205) worked! Thanks a lot, sir.

Comment: Fixed answer, with your notes )

Comment: waitKey(0) is working fine too! But to run the code after that we need to press a key